# Turn off motion blur in cuts

Tags: camera, motion-blur

How do I turn off Motion Blur when cutting the camera (when the camera immediately moves to a new location in one frame)?

Comment: Nice question! If you mean to avoid objects blurring and looking like ghosts, I have an answer for that.

Comment: Yes, I do mean that. Thanks for your answer. It really helps.

Comment: Unfortunately even now that they added MB in Eevee, there's no option to keyframe it... which sucks... the only way to prevent unwanted artifacts now is probably to render each piece separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution: It requires some manual labor.
**Update:** Only works for Cycles
I will be saying "Ghost Effect" a lot in this answer. The image is what I mean by that.
[image: Ghost Effect]

First, locate the property titled "Position" in the Motion Blur panel. The position property defines how the Motion Blur is calculated:
**Start on Frame**: The Motion Blur is calculated through the current frame and the frame right after it.
**Center on Frame**: Calculated through `frame - 1`, `frame`, and `frame + 1`.
**End on Frame**: Calculated through `frame - 1` and `frame`.
With these three settings, you can remove the "Ghost Effect" of motion blur with this procedure: Let's say that the cut is happening on `frame` and `frame + 1`. If you use the default **Center on Frame**, both `frame` and `frame + 1` will have the ghost effect, because the Motion Blur calculates with neighboring frames.
 To fix this, keep it on **Center on Frame**, go to `frame - 1`, hover over the property with your mouse, and press 'i' to add a keyframe. Then, go to `frame` and change it to **End on Frame** and add a keyframe. Then, go to `frame + 1` and add a keyframe on **Start on Frame**. Last, add a keyframe on **Center on Frame** for `frame + 2`. In total, you will need to add 4 keyframes.
Here's an explanation of what this is doing:
On frames that are not in the cut, the Motion Blur computes on **Center on Frame**. When it reaches the first frame of the cut, it performs on **End on Frame**. **End on Frame** computes with `frame - 1` and `frame`, as stated above. Because the cut happens on `frame` and `frame + 1`, the Motion Blur does not reach the cut, and will eliminate the "Ghost Effect". This can also be applied to the next frames.

Comment: There is a problem that you can not keyframe shutter in eevee...

Comment: @Tokenyet he said it is cycles only

Comment: @Eric Xue, that was an update after reading Tokenyet's comment, but thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Comment: @Eric Xue , Oh, Sorry, I missed that word. I potentialy feel this is for eevee since the date is May 27, 2020 :P

Comment: @Tokenyet i guess, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some researches at eevee.

I tried `Multiple Camera`, this could pass motion blur on some scene, but for the object that used from last scene, It will cause ghost effect on the object.

Let me think simply, why not just render the whole animation again **without motion blur**? The disadvantage for this is to render twice, and It's a big waste of time.

The final workaround I come up with, is to check which frames are the problem frames, and write It down. Then just manually render those transition cuts and replace the problem frames. This could be more easier with writing a batch script, then passing a sequence of frame number from the note. (don't forget to turn off motion blur)

Just my two cents, hope It help.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 3.1, tested in Cycles. When I keyframe the motion blur shutter, it keyframes it but it cannot be changed if keyframed again.

I did figure out though that you can keyframe the rolling shutter to "top to bottom" and set the value to 0 which seems to take away all the blur for just that frame. You can then keyframe one frame before and after to reset the rolling shutter back to "none" and restore the blur.

What am I using it for? A scene for work that has a semi truck rolling down the freeway and I wanted to put the project name and people on the side of the semi trailer. It was too blurry to read it though and now I can. I already had everything done and thought of this at the last minute and did not want to move a ton of keyframes for the rest of the scene and mess something up.

Otherwise I was going to have to rerun that frame set without motion blur and re-add it. This is fine if you do it once, but not if you have to keep doing it finding things to fix overall.